# Find files with a string in filename and unzip

Tags: linux, terminal, find, unzip, gnu-parallel

I have a folder full to zip files. Using  linux terminal, I need to find files with a certain string in the zip file name and unzip only them to another folder. I tried the following but no luck.

```
find /some_folder/ -name "*[temperature]*.zip" | parallel unzip '/some_folder/unzippedfiles/'
```

First, the pattern is not matching and second, I am not sure if the output could be redirected to another folder. Could someone suggest a fix please? Thanks a advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`/some_folder/` must be absolute path:

```
find /some_folder/ -name "*temperature*.zip" |
  parallel 'mkdir -p /some_folder/unzippedfiles/; cd /some_folder/unzippedfiles/ && unzip'
```

Comment: I accepted your answer. However, it assumes i have manually created the 'unzippedfiles' subfolder.

Comment: I have changed the answer, so you do not need to manually create the dir.

Answer (score 1):

To find a pattern in file names and unzip to a new folder

```
find /some_folder/ -name "*temperature*.zip" |
    parallel "mkdir -p {//}/unzippedfiles && cd {//}/unzippedfiles && unzip -q {}"
```

To ignore files with a pattern file names and unzip to a new folder

```
find /some_folder/ ! -name "*temperature*.zip" |
    parallel "mkdir -p {//}/unzippedfiles && cd {//}/unzippedfiles && unzip -q {}"

mkdir -p --> Creates a folder if it does not exist
-q --> quiet mode 
{//} --> mydir/mysubdir (In this case, it is /some_folder)
```